# PDF in <iframe> not working on tablets

Tags: php, pdf, iframe

I'm trying to place PDF in `<iframe>` for my web application. Works fine on all major desktop browsers but doesn't seem to be working on mobile devices. The files are downloaded instead any solution to this?

Comment: what do you mean by "placing a pdf"? Displaying PDFs is not a default feature of browsers, this is slowly coming up. Tablet and Mobile browsers can't display PDF directly at the moment. Or are you using a JavaScript framewwork to render the PDF somehow?

Comment: @bmurauer I'm trying to display the pdfs in the iframe is the any way to go around it on mobile browsers and tablets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the PDF in a browser manually (as mobile browsers usually don't feature  this automatically), you'd have to use some JavaScript framework like [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Modern Browsers like Chrome or Firefox have special renderers built-in, whereas mobile browsers don't.